# stack for tracking python indentation levels

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to track indentation levels in python through a stack in scheme/racket

The stack will have a series of numbers with the number of spaces of each indentation level. A space is counted as 1 and a tab according with python's spec is "Tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces such that the total number of characters up to and including the replacement is a multiple of eight (this is intended to be the same rule as used by Unix)."

I am not sure how/when to pop one or more levels from the stack or how to count the tabs

So far I came out with this

```
(define stack 0)

(define push-to-stack! num-spaces (set! stack (cons num-spaces stack)))

(define pop-one-from-stack! ...)

(define pop-multiple-from-stack! ...)

(define num_spaces-for-a-tab ...)
```

Comment: This feels like a very imperative (and therefore, very un-Racket-y) approach to trying something like this. What are you trying to do this for?

Comment: I am new to racket and this is just a learning experience: I would like to keep track of the indentation levels in a python program

Answer (score 0):

Counting indentation WRT tabs: When you encounter a tab, it counts as only
enough to bring the count so far up to the next multiple of 8.

```
(require (planet jphelps/loop))

(define (indentation-level line)
  (loop for ch across line
    while (or (eq? ch #\space)
              (eq? ch #\tab))
    count (eq? ch #\space) into spaces
    when (eq? ch #\tab) do
      (set! spaces (- (+ spaces 8)
                      (modulo (+ spaces 8) 8)))
    finally (return spaces)))
```

As far as keeping a stack, maybe what you'd want to keep track of is the line preceding the increase in indentation, and that line's indentation level (which would be the "if", "when", "for", "def" that the code you're currently reading is supposed to be a part of).

In any case, your stack is a list, so an empty stack is represented as '(), not 0. Because Racket's (define) form only defines constants when used within a module, you have to use a box or a parameter to be able to change it:

```
(define stack (box '()))
```

Pushing onto the stack (no ! at the end of the name because it doesn't modify its argument):

```
(define (push something)
   (box-set! stack (cons something stack)))
```

Popping one or many (n is an optional argument):

```
(define (pop (n #f))
  (if (not n)
      (and (not (null? (unbox stack)))
       (let ((last-push (car (unbox stack))))
         (set-box! stack (cdr (unbox stack)))
         last-push))
      (loop repeat n collect (pop))))
```